# Placing the element to a specific position

Tags: html, css

I just wanted a bit of help. I wanted to move my `div` element to about 25% top from right most bottom of the display. Is the below CSS code correct?

```
.positioning {
   vertical-align: bottom;
   text-align: right;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="positioning">
   //Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.positioning {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioning">
  25% top from Right bottom
</div>
```